# How to build nodejs C++ addon depending on a shared library with relative location

Tags: node.js, gcc, node-modules, node-gyp, compiler-flags

I'm trying to build a node.js C++ using `node-gyp` but can't figure out how to specify the `-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN` so that when loaded from node it could find shared object library that is in the same directory as `addon.node`.

I have tried setting my `binding.gyp` like this:

```
"libraries": [
          "-L../../install_release_x64/",
          "-llibppp"
        ],
        "ldflags": [
          "-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'"
        ],
        "cflags_cc": [
          "-fexceptions",
          "-fPIC",
          "-Wno-unknown-pragmas"
        ]
```

but when I run `$ readelf -d addon.node` the result is like this:

```
 Dynamic section at offset 0x7d10 contains 29 entries:
Tag        Type                         Name/Value
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [liblibppp.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [addon.node]
0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [RIGIN]
0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x37a0
```

The expected result is `Library rpath: [$ORIGIN]`

Any ideas what's node-gyp doing to my `$ORIGIN` special keyword?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like I have to escape it like this:

```
"ldflags": [
    "-Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN'"
],
```

Now it works like expected.