# N-API include an .so or dll

Tags: c++, node.js, electron

I am developing an app using electron.

I have setup an addon that uses c++ code and translated it into nodejs code using NAPI.

Now I want to include an external .so library (with a .h file) but can't find any documents that achieve any success.

I keep getting error: undefined symbol: Some_Function_Name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specifiy libraries to link against in the `binding.gyp`, details is in [Node-gyp/C++ import shared library (.so)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50531237/node-gyp-c-import-shared-library-so) and **[How to build nodejs C++ addon depending on a shared library with relative location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512623/how-to-build-nodejs-c-addon-depending-on-a-shared-library-with-relative-locati)**. when using NAPI you use `node-gyp` as the toolchain to compile automatically, is a dependency of NAPI

Comment: I checked those, seemed I made a silly mistake in my binding.gyp file, the problem was that the "libraries" tag was not included in the "targets" tag I had included it on its own.

I am getting some errors now but will debug, thanks